# Is PAM a user authentication method?

Tags: pam

If someone asks that **PAM is a user authentication method**?

Then can we say yes? Or no?

Comment: PAM = Pluggable authentication module?

Comment: Have you done any research on PAM? It's not a simple subject, and the question can be interpreted a number of ways.

Comment: No. A system is not a method.

Comment: "A system is not a method" sounds oxymoronic to me, considering that *systematic* and *methodical* are near synonyms.  The answer here depends on context.  IMO it is probably *yes*, but if the context is "I'm playing semantic games with someone", then it is either yes or no, but either way you will be wrong ;)

Comment: @goldilocks - just for fun, let's assume we are *playing [a] semantic game*. To that end I'll play [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/system?s=t)'s 4th definition of *system*: *a coordinated body of methods or a scheme or plan of procedure*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

PAM is a framework for authentication using different pam modules. The benefit to this is that application developers do not have to write the authentication logic themselves; e.g. it provides standards: from `man 7 pam`: `Linux-PAM is a system of libraries that handle the authentication tasks of applications (services) on the system.`

PAM does provide user authentication, but it also provides other things such as system limits (`pam_limits`), motd (`pam_motd`), shell validation (`pam_shell`), LDAP authentication (`pam_ldap`), MySQL authentication (`pam_mysql`), etc.

You can see most of the functionality of `pam` by reading the [system admins guide](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/Linux-PAM_SAG.html).

Comment: If PAM "does provide [a means or method of] user authentication", then how is the answer to the question "No"?  This is like saying that a highway is not a method of transportation because it just provides a framework so that vehicles can do it for themselves.  Never-the-less, a decent answer in terms of information.

Comment: Hmm. Very well put. I retract my comment and will delete it. Thank you. I will not however retract the upvote I gave this post before even making it.